# How can I merge several images via loop using the information of a dataframe on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, python-imaging-library

I have the following dictionary:

```
the_dictionary_list = {'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'],
                       'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 
                       'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'],
                       'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 
                       'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 
                       'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

To get each possible permutation without repetition in a specific order (i.e. cartesian products) I use the following code:

```
import itertools as it

AllKeysNames = ['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas']
Combinations = list(it.product(*(the_dictionary_list[Name] for Name in AllKeysNames)))
print(f'{Combinations}')
```

Then, for saving each iteration to a dataframe such as it throws an output like this one:

```
   |            Permutations            |                                    FilePermutations                                      |
  0|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+None                         |
  1|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Arena.png                    |
  2|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Marron.png                   |
  3|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Purpura.png                  |
  4|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+None+Verde.png                    |
  5|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+None                 |
  6|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+Arena.png            |
  7|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+Marron.png           |
  8|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+Purpura.png          |
  9|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Antenas.png+Amarillo.png+Pinzitas.png+Verde.png            |
  .
  .
  .
358|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Verticales.png+Zapote.png+Pinzota_pinzita.png+Purpura.png  |
359|Fondo+Cuerpo+Ojos+Color+Pinzas+Puas |Oceano.png+Cuerpo_cangrejo.png+Verticales.png+Zapote.png+Pinzota_pinzita.png+Verde.png    |
```

I use the following code:

```
new = ['+'.join(x) for x in 
                        it.product(*(the_dictionary_list[Name] for Name in AllKeysNames))]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Permutations':"+".join(AllKeysNames), 'FilePermutations':new})
```

Now, suppose that the above program is located in the same path (i.e. `r"./"`) in which *coincidentally* the following folders are also located:

[image: Folders]

These folders only contain file images, which *also coincidentally* have the same name of those values in `the_dictionary_list`.

**As the `df` variable has stored the right order in which these images must be merged besides the filenames and foldernames, and also the total amount of permutations**

**How could this program take that information from the** `df` **and use the functions of:**

`Image.open(r"./")`

`Image.alpha_composite()`

`resize((350, 350), resample=Image.NEAREST`

from `Python Imaging Library (PIL)`

To produce the new merged images in the order in which the `df` shows it?

*Notes:*

> The image filenames can be equal to the respective index of `df`.
>
> As the `None` element doesn't actually exist in the folders,  when needed, the program would have to merge the previous images with the next one (i.e. not calling `Image.open(r"./")` nor `Image.alpha_composite()` when '`None`' appears and continue to do so with the next element)
>
> Only after having merged the file images of a row, it would call `resize((350, 350), resample=Image.NEAREST` for then saving the final output using `.save(r"./Test/str(Index(i))+".png")` and then repeat the process until it has reached the final index of `df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution was built by [@christian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/183782/christian) from **stackoverflow en español**, the translation of his answer is the following:

> Pandas DataFrames have a method called iterrorws() that returns a
> generator and we can iterate through it, this returns the row
> itself as a tuple that contains two objects, the first one is the index of
> the row and the second one is a Pandas Series that contains the values
> of the next columns.
>
> I would not recommend joining the names with a `+`, you can simply leave
> them in list format since later we will need them as lists again and
> you can save that conversion to a list by avoiding using `'+'.join(x)`.

```
for i, per in df.iterrows(): 
    images = per["FilePermutations"].split("+")
    files = per["Permutations"].split("+")
```

> With this we are obtaining the value of the respective column and we
> convert it back to a list with the help of the `split` method. Once we
> have this we can move on to create the new image that is the result of
> joining all the images specified in the `images` list. For this, we must
> first know the directory of each image and "coincidentally" the first
> element of `files` list is the directory where the image of the
> first element of the `images` list is located, and so on for each of the
> images. It happened to use the `zip()` function that matches each of
> those elements (in case a list has fewer elements, it will only match
> up to the smallest list and will not include the others, in case there
> is that scenario you can use the `zip_longest` function from `itertools`
> module) . With that we would already have the `path` of the image, we
> would only have to open it, combine it and at the end of all resize it
> and save it.

```
for i, per in df.iterrows():
    images = per["FilePermutations"].split("+")
    files = per["Permutations"].split("+")
    result_image = None #aquí se almacenará la imagen resultante 

    for direc, img in zip(files, images): #iteramos
        if img=="None": continue #si es None omitimos

        path = f"{direc}/{img}" #definimos la ruta donde se encuentra la imagen
        
        #en la primera iteración no habrá imagen inicial por lo que no podrá combinarse con otra
        # por lo que asignamos la imagen
        if result_image == None: 
            result_image = Image.open(f"./{path}")
        else: #combinamos la imagen
            img2 = Image.open(f"./{path}")
            result_image = Image.alpha_composite(result_image, img2)
    # redimensionamos y guardamos
    result_image = result_image.resize((350, 350), resample=Image.NEAREST)
    result_image.save(f"./Test/image_{i}.png")
```

> This will combine all the specified images in each row and save them
> to the specified path. As you have seen there is not much magic in
> this, just a couple of `for` loops, the first to iterate through the
> rows and the second to create the `path` and get the images. In each
> iteration of the second `for` the result of `result_image` is overwritten
> so that it always contains the result of the combination of the
> current image and the previous one, in this way all the images are
> mixed, obviously those that do not exist marked as `'None'` are omitted

This answered my question incredibly well.